# is the big o runtime of an array.include method ran inside a for loop o(n) time?

Tags: javascript, big-o, computer-science

this is my code. pretty simple code for finding unique values within an array. i'm confused on whether this is n time or n^2 time because the number of times the uniqueValues array is looped through is related to how big the length is. so that makes it somewhat unrelated to the for loop doesnt it?

```
function countUniqueValues(array) {
  let uniqueArray = []; //constant
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) { //n time
    if (uniqueArray.includes(array[i])) { //n time 
    } else {
      uniqueArray.push(array[i]); //constant time
    }
    console.log(i) //constant
    console.log(uniqueArray) //constant
  
  }
  console.log(uniqueArray.length);
  return uniqueArray.length;
}
countUniqueValues([1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 7, 7, 12, 12, 13]);
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, if you want to treat them as unrelated, you'd say `O(n*m)` where `n` is the number of items in the array and `m` is the number of unique items. However for a given (or average) relative uniqueness of the items in the array, and certainly for the worst case of 100% uniqueness, `m = O(n)` so we simplify to `O(n²)`.